# How Can I convert this raw sql query to laravel AR

Tags: php, laravel, activerecord

I want to get the number of boys from the students table. This student table is connected to the users table with user_id and the users table is connected to the genders table with gender_id.

I have the raw query and it works. I only want a way to convert it to AR.

```
DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u, students s WHERE s.user_id = u.id AND u.gender_id = 2');
```

Relations,

```
public function user()
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id'); 
} 

public function gender(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo(Gender::class, 'gender_id'); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have relations between the entities set up? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes I do. 

students:
                                                               public function user(){
  public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

users:

 public function gender(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Gender::class, 'gender_id');
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relation between student and user models you can use this.

```
 Student::query()->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
        $q->where('gender_id', 2);
    })->count();
```